# Has anyone implemented a git clone or interface library using nodejs?

Tags: git, node.js

I'm looking for an implementation of git which is accessible from nodejs - does such a beast exist?

Comment: I am curious why this is closed. The question is concise, unambiguous, narrow and - above all - evidently answerable. What am I missing? Was it closed without any comments that would indicate how to improve it? Just seems odd. :)

Comment: Also check out https://github.com/qrpike/NodeJS-Git-Server for a git server written in NodeJS

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt: Asking for  tools is considered a bad habbit. The reasoning is that it is not really a programming issue and will lead to fanboy wars. IMHO those "bad" qustions helped me out a lot and I will miss them.

Comment: "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form"—none, NONE of the reasons is remotely valid. proof: the OP's question may truthfully be answered by "yes", as demonstrated below. it is also a genuine programming question. i for one am always happy to see when knowledgeable readers manage to post an answer before the keepers march in.

Comment: I was so sad to see there was no way to report / down-vote the 5 people who wrongly closed this very legitimate question.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt, this types of question can be asked at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Looks like there are now several options for using git from node:

- gift: simple Node.js wrapper for the Git CLI with an API based on Grit ([npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gift) / [github](https://github.com/notatestuser/gift))
- node-git: a node.js git implementation modeled on grit ([npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/git) / [github](https://github.com/christkv/node-git/))
- nodegit: libgit2 asynchronous native bindings ([npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodegit) / [github](https://github.com/tbranyen/nodegit))
- node-git: a thin wrapper around the command-line git command ([github](https://github.com/creationix/node-git/))

Comment: node-git doesn't work on 0.8 :(

Comment: node-git is now tested on nodes 0.10 and 0.11 on travis ci, should be well.

Answer (score 31):

Note sure if there's a git library for Node but you can also just execute a shell process directly, example:

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("git status", puts);
```

Answer (score 5):

there is also **[node-gitteh](http://libgit2.github.com/node-gitteh/)** as libgit2 bindings, but both gitteh and christkv/node-git were not of the quality and completeness I needed

I wrote **[treeeater](https://github.com/payload/node-treeeater/)** a spawn git wrapper, which is callable with plain javascript objects instead of strings, can parse some output (git log → commit objects, git ls-tree → tree object hierachy) and runs async. It is in active use and supports all git commands, atleast for calling them and piping their output chunk or line wise. You can stick to git man-pages to get the documentation to each command.

Comment: I'd advise against using node-gitteh. It's not well maintained at all.