# Writing git API for javascript node module

Tags: javascript, git, api, node.js

Hi recently I have to implement a git API for a node module, so we can have version control through programmatic interface. I came upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955891/has-anyone-implemented-a-git-clone-or-interface-library-using-nodejs) to find some good modules that I can use.

However, after playing around with some of them, I realized that none of them provide the feature of querying the commit history of a single file (like calling 'git log --follow '). I would like to extend that feature into my module but since I have no experience before, does anyone know where I should start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries you mentioned should be a good starting point. Take [node-git's lib/git.js file](https://github.com/christkv/node-git/blob/master/lib/git/git.js) for example. There you can find the following lines:

```
// Call the native git binary
Git.prototype.call_git = function(prefix, command, postfix, options, args, callback) {
    // ...
```

This is a good starting point to understand how the author maps Node functions on system calls and and allows the callback to work with the output.

I would start a fork of the project. Look for the log function in the [same file](https://github.com/christkv/node-git/blob/master/lib/git/git.js), which starts like

```
Git.prototype.log = function(commit, path, options, callback) {
```

Copy the function, give it a proper name and try to adopt it to meet your needs.

If you succeed and like to help, you could start a pull request on GitHub to help the author and add the functionallity to the official project.

I would do it this way. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Seb, actually I decided to just dive into the source code and found that to be pretty clearly documented. I should be able to extend the module smoothly :)