# Can git commits be squashed from a node.js script?

Tags: git, node.js

I would like to be able to squash the last n commits that have a commit message of 'squash commit' into a single commit from a node.js script. The only way that I know of to squash commits is through an interactive rebase, is there a way to do this from a node script?

Ex:

```
> git log --oneline | head -4
ecce153 Do not change commit
dd831f6 squash commit
c20677a squash commit
86b52fb squash commit

> ./squash.js "New commit made by squashing 3 'squash commit' commits."
ecce153 Do not change commit
as34dwf New commit made by squashing 3 'squash commit' commits.
```

Going off of this SO post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5956198/626759, I could get to the interactive rebase easily enough, but how could I work with that from a node script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do a rebase to squash n commits:

```
git reset HEAD~4
git add .
git commit -m "squashed four commits"
```

This backs up HEAD four commits, but preserves the present changes in the working directory, then adds and commits those changes in a single commit.

Even shorter version

```
git reset --soft HEAD~4
git commit -m "squashed four commits"
```

`--soft` preserves the index too, so you don't have to `add`.