# How to use command 'git clone url' in nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, clone

I am trying to clone a git url in NodeJs(Server side) Application. Do any one have idea on how to do so. I wanted to run the git clone command through node server javascript file.

Comment: have you googled it?

Comment: It depends on the OS that you are using not the language.. And I dont think Node JS is any Operating system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has anyone implemented a git clone or interface library using nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955891/has-anyone-implemented-a-git-clone-or-interface-library-using-nodejs)

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a the `nodegit` plugin:

https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit

Sample (for more info see http://www.nodegit.org/api/):

```
var clone = require("nodegit").Clone.clone;

// Clone a given repository into a specific folder.
clone("https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit", "tmp")
  .then(function () {
    // Repo is available in "tmp"
  });
```