# Manage git repo from node.js application

Tags: node.js, git, nodegit

I need to manage a [git](https://git-scm.com/) repository from a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) application. Is there a **git** wrapper library or something that lets me call **git** functions high level and interpret the result without having to parse the console output?

Comment: **See Also**: [Has anyone implemented a git clone or interface library using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5955891/1366033)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for http://www.nodegit.org/ ?

`npm install nodegit`

Comment: nodegit is a binding for libgit2, does it mean I won't need git installed in the system where the app is running?

Comment: If you have gitlib2 installed thats enough